# Como consumir desde Java un Web Service hecho en PHP

Tags: php, java, webservice, netbeans, wsdl

tengo un Web Service hecho en php, cuando intento crear un cliente en Java para consumirlo, me aparece el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto en varias páginas que para instalar el plugin faltante se debe usar este enlace http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

Pero no me funciona, me aparece este otro error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De esa forma solo se utiliza cuando el web service es de `java`, lo que tienes que hacer es crear una clase y hacer la llamada desde ahi solo validar que responda `ok`.

Este podria ser un ejemplo del codigo que podrias usar

```
try {
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost/tuUrl.php?parametro=xxx"); 

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("").get(ClientResponse.class);

if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
 throw new RuntimeException("Fallo : Codigo HTTP error : " + response.getStatus());
}

String salida = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("\n============Plain Text Response============");
System.out.println(output2);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```